# Gradle equivalent of grails.plugin.location

Tags: grails, gradle

I have a project A and project B in same directory. Project A uses grails 2.5.1 and project B uses grails 3.2.2.

Normally in grails, to include project B we use:

```
grails.plugin.location.'projectB'='../projectB'
```

in buildconfig.groovy of project A.

Is there an equivalent way to do this in build.gradle?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a Gradle multi project build.

The Grails docs show you how to have an app and local plugins participate in the same gradle build:

See: Plugins and Multi-Project Builds
http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/plugins.html